# Data in int* argument of function not returned caller

Tags: c++, pointers

Compiled with g++ on WSL2, sample output of

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

vector <int> powers_2(const int npow) {
    vector <int> v;
    int j = 2;
    for (int i=0; i<npow; i++) {
        v.push_back(j);
        j*= 2;
    }
    return v;
}

void pow_2(const int npow, int *v, int *nv) {
    vector <int> w = powers_2(npow);
    *nv = w.size();
    v = (int*)malloc(*nv * sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<*nv; i++) {
        v[i] = w[i];
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,v[i],w[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int *y;
    int ny;
    pow_2(3,y,&ny);
    printf("\n in main\n");
    for (int i=0; i<ny; i++) {
      printf("%d %d\n",i,y[i]);
    }
}
```

is

```
0 2 2
1 4 4
2 8 8

 in main
0 1
1 0
2 1091723517
```

So the argument `int* v` is set in pow_2, but the data is not returned to caller. Why?

Comment: The function `void pow_2(const int npow, int *v, int *nv)`, argument `v` is a pointer to int. But in the function body, we made `v` to point to somewhere else, which has nothing to do with the original place pointed by `v`. That's why the caller does not see any update in the original place it has prepared.

Comment: Use `std::vector<int> pow_2(int npow)`. Best to forget about C-style arrays. Actually just remove `pow_2` completely as `powers_2` already does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between passing function arguments [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm), [by pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm).

The line

```
pow_2(3,y,&ny);
```

will pass the value of `y` to the function `pow_2`, which means that a copy of the value of the variable `y` will be made, which will exist as the local variable `v` in the function `pow_2`. This is not what you want, because changing the variable `v` in the function `pow_2` will only change that variable, but it won't change the value of the original variable `y` in the function `main`.

What you instead want is to pass the variable `y` itself to the function `pow_2`, not its value, so that it can be changed by the function `pow_2`. There are two ways of doing this. You can pass the variable `y`

- as a reference, or
- as a pointer

to the function `pow_2`.

To make the function `pow_2` take a reference to an `int *` instead of the value of an `int *`, you can change the line

```
void pow_2(const int npow, int *v, int *nv) {
```

to:

```
void pow_2(const int npow, int * &v, int *nv) {
```

Alternatively, you can make the function `pow_2` take a pointer to an `int *` instead of the value of an `int *`. You can change the line

```
void pow_2(const int npow, int *v, int *nv) {
```

to

```
void pow_2(const int npow, int **v, int *nv) {
```

However, this will require you to rewrite the function `pow_2` so that the pointer is deferenced whenever it is used:

```
void pow_2(const int npow, int **v, int *nv) {
    vector <int> w = powers_2(npow);
    *nv = w.size();
    *v = (int*)malloc(*nv * sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<*nv; i++) {
        (*v)[i] = w[i];
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,(*v)[i],w[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, you will have to call the function differently. You will have to change the line

```
pow_2(3,y,&ny);
```

to:

```
pow_2(3,&y,&ny);
```

Therefore, passing the variable as a reference is easier than passing it as a pointer.